# Method not found UseSqlServer

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I'm trying to create DbContextOptionBuilder and run into an error at runtime that says the next:

> Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder`1<!!0> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder`1, System.String, System.Action`1)'.

Code that trying to create it:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
var newDbConnectionString = "myconnectionString";

optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(newDbConnectionString);
```

I have installed all required packages, such as

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

My using block:

> using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling;
>   using System;
>   using System.ComponentModel;
>   using System.Data.SqlClient;
>   using System.Threading;
>   using Cloud.DbManager.Models;
>   using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Comment: Have you tried restarting VS?  I've had a few instances where I've installed packages but they haven't appeared to be installed, only for a restart to fix it.

Comment: @Tom No, it doesn't work for me. I even restarted my PC. The interesting part is that i can observe this method through metadata but once i get method where it is used i get an error

Comment: Please show your `using` section.

Comment: @Miamy updated description

Comment: Check in Nuget manager if you have no Entity Framework packages installed. I had some odd errors when both EF and EF Core packages were installed by mistake.